# EZAudio framework -"Error: Couldn't initialize output unit ('fmt?')"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, ezaudio

I am using EZAudio framework (https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio) and when trying to initialize my output with a custom AudioStreamBasicDescription like so...

```
- (void)openMediaPlayer {
    // Initialize the EZOutput instance and assign it a delegate to provide the output audio data
    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioDesc;
    audioDesc.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioDesc.mSampleRate = 44100;
    audioDesc.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    audioDesc.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
    audioDesc.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    audioDesc.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
    audioDesc.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    audioDesc.mReserved = 0;
    self.output = [EZOutput outputWithDataSource:self withAudioStreamBasicDescription:audioDesc];
    self.currentAudioPieceIndex = 0;
}
```

I get the error "Error: Couldn't initialize output unit ('fmt?')"

What does this mean?  AudioDesc is set with sane defaults for PCM 16 bit stereo audio.

Update:  When I use the debugger I found I was getting OSStatus 1718449215.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you have to set

```
audioDesc.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;
```

When your audio format is PCM.